# Проверка пинга хоста на Python

Tags: python, ip, ос, ping

Есть небольшой скрипт, где я подключаюсь к свитчам по телнету. Но перед этим нужно проверить доступен ли он. Программа работает, но если свитч недоступен программа не останавливается, пока я принудительно это не сделаю. Подскажите как сделать чтобы программа завершала процесс когда хост недоступен

```
import telnetlib
import os

Host = input("Введите Ip адрес свитча: ")
Ping = os.system("ping -c 1 " + Host)

if Ping == 0:

    User = input("Username: ").encode()
    Password = input("Password: ").encode()
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(Host)
    tn.read_until(b'Username:')
    tn.write(User + b'\n')
    tn.read_until(b'Password:')
    tn.write(Password + b'\n')

    tn.write(b'terminal length 512' + b'\n')
    inputCommand = input("Введите команду: ").encode()
    tn.write(inputCommand + b'\n')
    exitLine = input("Введите exit для завершения: ").encode()
    tn.write(exitLine + b'\n')
    showInf = tn.read_all().decode()
    print(showInf)

else:

    print(Host, "Недоступен")
```

Comment: можете указать в вопросе какая у вас OS? Если у вас Windows, то `ping -c 1` надо заменить на `ping -n 1`

Comment: Делаю все это на линуксе

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку `pythonping`.

Пример:

```py
if ping("8.8.8.8", verbose=false)[0].success:
    print("Successful!")
```

Можете больше почитать в документации. 
`verbose` - отвечает за вывод на экран, функция возвращает массив ответов. 
Чтобы выйти из программы, вызвав соответствующую функцию, вызовите `sys.exit(0)`, перед этим импортировав `sys`

Comment: моя проблема заключается в том, что если хост недоступен он не завершает программу, а нужно самому принудительно ее остановить, после чего он выводит сообщение что "такой то" хост недоступен

Comment: Тогда вам нужно сначала вывести сообщение и затем вызвать функцию `sys.exit(0)`. Перед этим, импортировав `import sys`

Comment: Я вам помог? Если да то приймите пожалуйста мой ответ